# how to keep child element centered vertically and horizontally without using positioning properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three div as shown below. I want to keep inner div in exactly center of outer div. I found some solution with position style set, but it was creating problem with my other element in my project, so I don't want to use position in style. I want to center inner div without using position style.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: abhishek, wanted solution without using positions..the simple one as show in below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
#outer {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center #inner horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* center #inner vertically */
}
```

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcfc84qq/1/)

Comment: thanks..your solution did work. just updated fiddle link for others  http://jsfiddle.net/shyam_bhiogade/r26vc8t6/

Comment: hi michael, i have also updated another solution..do you see any issue in that. thanks

Comment: No issues with tables. That's another way to center things. I prefer flexbox because it's responsive, flexible and specifically designed for layouts.

Comment: hey michael, the solution i gave also works.can you please upvote it.

Comment: @shyam_, if it works I will upvote. But I tested it before and it didn't work. And the demo uses different code than posted in the answer: Your answer uses table properties, but your demo uses flexbox. Please update your answer and post a working demo so I can upvote.

Answer (score 2):

found another solution

```
#outer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#inner {
    margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dspLofov/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would center a div inside a div, the css is as follows

```
#outer {

    background: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    resize: both;
    padding: 1em;
}
//I put color in the background so it is easy to see.
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwillhite/464Lf6wr/embedded/result/

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi David i do not wanted to use the position style element, its interfering with my positioned element on the page...thanks for your reply.

Comment: Oops!, I'm sorry I misunderstood.  It seems as if the flexbox is working though so that is good.

Comment: hey david, the solution i gave also works.can you please upvote it.